# Using the PAQ8 compression algorithm

Tags: c#, compression

I'm trying to get a working port of the PAQ8 algorithm in C#, but I haven't been able to find any. Are there any ways to get it in C# or has there not been anything made yet?

I'm willing to sacrifice a lot of speed to get the compression rates that PAQ8 promises.

Comment: This would probably be better on Programmers stackexchange since it is not a programming question that fits this forum. That being said, I am not aware of any port to C#. Sounds like an interesting side-project though, since source code for the C++ project is available here: http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/compression/paq.html#paq8